# how do I get date time including milliseconds in VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a VBA macro  ( excel vba ) where I have some code querying a SQL Server database field. The field is of type datetime
The field has values including milliseconds.

if I query the field with ADO and the Recordset will give me teh field value formatted and without the milliseconds bit
for example the actual field value when queries in SQL management studio
is
2015-12-14 10:19:48.077
but the recordset value is
14/12/2015 10:19:48 AM

How can I get the actual value ?

Comment: What have you done so far to try to solve this problem?  You might be able to manipulate the SQL string to add the necessary formatting.  But since you chose not to post your code, it is difficult to be specific. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Because a `Date` variable *(which includes times)* does not support milliseconds, consider using a `Double` variable.

Comment: An internet search reveals a number of hits addressing this problem.  Which did you try, and what happened?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I find it interesting also that the VBA `Format` function does not seem to support milliseconds either; although the cell property `NumberFormat` does as does `WorksheetFunction.Text`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Just not enough bits.................in VBA `Dates` go way below 1900.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting as string.  Like This in SQL Server.

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(50), GETDATE(), 113) as MyDateAsStringWithMS
```

Casting a date as string is useful in scenarios where your are converting between SQL and ORACLE and MySQL and ODBC level libraries like in Java and VBA and COM.

I chose 113 on purpose.  I have had a lot of success using that format when I want milliseconds.